# Return View with model after AJAX call

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an MVC project where i need to pass some complex data from view to controller

I do that by using ajax. Here's my View:

```
<input type="button" value="Aph" id="Aph" />

@section Scripts{
<script>
        var ids = [];

        $("body").on("click", "#Aph", function () {
            console.log("aaaaa");
            let dict = {
                "Investigative" :0,
                "Social" : 0,
                "Realist" : 0,
                "Artistic" : 0,
                "Antreprenorial" : 0,
                "Conventional" : 0
                };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/User/GoThroughQuestions',
                data: {pageNumber : 0 , partialResults: dict, questionnaireName :"APH"},
                success: function (response) {
                  
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error while getting data");
        }
    });

        });
</script>
}
```

And here's my controller:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> GoThroughQuestionsAsync(int pageNumber, Dictionary<string, int> partialResults, string questionnaireName, Result? finalResults =null)
    {
        if (finalResults == null)
            finalResults = new Result();
        finalResults.Social = finalResults.Social + partialResults["Social"];
        finalResults.Conventional = finalResults.Conventional + partialResults["Conventional"];
        finalResults.Antreprenorial = finalResults.Antreprenorial + partialResults["Antreprenorial"];
        finalResults.Realist = finalResults.Realist + partialResults["Realist"];
        finalResults.Artistic = finalResults.Artistic + partialResults["Artistic"];
        finalResults.Investigative = finalResults.Investigative + partialResults["Investigative"];

        var questions = UserService.GetQuestionnaireQuestions(questionnaireName, pageNumber);

        QuestionnaireInProgressViewModel inProgressViewModel = new QuestionnaireInProgressViewModel()
        {
            Questions = questions,
            FinalResult = finalResults,
            QuestionnaireName = questionnaireName
        };
        return View(inProgressViewModel);
    }
```

My controller does everything right but when it returns the View the page doesnt change.

I know that i can RedirectToAction in Ajax succes function with windows.href  but i have that really complex model that i dont know how to pass (or even get back from the controller).

I have also read that ajax is mainly used to refresh only a portion of the page and that if i want to redirect to a different page i should do a simple post request, but i dont know how to do that either (since i have to pass more complex structures such as dictionaries). Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried to change the return type of the method to JSON? In success function, you can place returned data to an element like $("#label_QuestionnaireName).val(response.QuestionnaireName)

Comment: Try `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult` and on `success` function call `location.reaload()` method